# How to connect to Neo4j from a web browser

Tags: neo4j

I am just getting started with Neo4j and when I try to run a command that connects to the database I get an error.  For example, if I try to run the first `CREATE` command from the sample movie database, or if I run `CALL dbms.procedures()`.

The error is as follows: `BoltConnectionError: No connection found, did you connect to Neo4j?`

In the left panel of the browser page, under the 'Connected As' heading, it has my username and role (Admin).  FYI, I followed the setup procedure from Larave's Homestead to install Neo4j in the first instance.  On my first visit to the URL (port 7474), it asked for (and accepted) my username and password.

Additional Info:

- Neo4j database is version 3.3.5 and runs on a Ubuntu VM
- Neo4j browser is ver 3.1.7 and runs on the mac host
- When I run `:server connect` it tells me I am connected via bolt://mydomain:7687
- When I run `lsof -i :7474` on the Ubuntu machine it tells me that Java is listening to the port, and that user is neo4j

Comment: Please edit to provide platform, version.
Are server and browser running on same machine ?
Is bolt "running" on ITS default port ? (if that port was used at server startup, another port is attributed but webapp settings is still on default value)

Comment: Thanks @Jerome_B, see Additional Info heading above....

Comment: Can you try to do a `:server disconnect` and then a `:server connect` ? Does it work after ? Moreover, have you change the Neo4j configuration to allow Neo4j to listen on the network ?

Comment: Thanks @logisima, I tried disconnect/reconnect, but no success.  Also setup port forwarding for 7687, no change.  Not sure what you mean by setup config to listen, but this was automatically installed by Laravel, and their installs are usually correct.

Comment: Per default, Neo4j doesn't listen on the network (just local), so if you are trying to access it from an other computer, you have to change the Neo4j configuration :  `dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0`

Comment: Thanks @logisima, my default_listen_address is currently set to 0.0.0.0

Comment: What is your browser version (ie. firefox, chrome, IE ) ??Do you have some enterprise security on your laptop ?

Comment: Hey @logisima, thanks for the questions re browser.  I was using Firefox, so I swapped to Chrome and it worked straight away.  I then deleted the cookies in Firefox and it now works there too, though with the occasional error...

Answer (score 0):

First

```
:server disconnect
```

And then connect again

```
:server connect
```

If it doesn't work, change your browser.